# Directorios y ficheros en Java

Tags: java, rutas

Tengo el siguiente programa:

- Si es fichero quiero que me muestre (`ruta`, `nombre`, `tamaño`)
- Si no es fichero entonces muestra que es un directorio.

El dato lo saca del parámetro.

El código:

```
        public class VeureInfo {
            public static void VeureInfo(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

                File origen = new File(filePath);
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(origen);   

                if (origen.isFile()){
                    System.out.println("Java VeureInfo " +origen.getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println("INFORMACIÓ: Informació sobre el fitxer:");
                    System.out.println("Nom del fitxer : "+origen.getName());
                    System.out.println("Ruta : "+origen.getPath());
                    System.out.println("Ruta Absoluta : "+origen.getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println("Es pot escriure : "+origen.canWrite());
                    System.out.println("Es pot lleguir : "+origen.canRead());
                    System.out.println("Grandaria : "+origen.length()+(" bytes"));

                }else{
                    System.out.println("directorio") ;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("No hi han fitxers visibles que cumpleixin amb el patró :"+filePath);   
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        VeureInfo.VeureInfo(args[0]);
    }
}
```

Tengo un problema:

Mi programa lee bien ambas cosas, es decir, ficheros y directorios. Pongo de parámetro un directorio y me salta error, es decir, me dice que no encuentra nada por el nombre del directorio... ¿Qué hay incorrecto?

Comment: ¿Qué error te salta, y en qué línea?

Comment: } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println("No hi han fitxers visibles que cumpleixin amb el patró :"+filePath);   
    }

Comment: ya esta lo he arreglado,modifico mi pregunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varios problemas en el tratamiento de excepciones:

- En el método estático con el nombre de la clase, debería ser el constructor de la clase o no llamar al método como a la clase.
- Para que sea el constructor, hay que quitar `static void` de la cabecera del método, o llamar a la función con otro nombre.
- Estás lanzando excepciones (sentencia `throws`) en el método `VeureInfo`.
- Tienes media sentencia `catch` para capturar una excepción (`try-catch` ¡Es una sentencia, no va separado uno de otro!).
- Si la lanzas en el método, no intentes capturarla también, o le cierras la puerta o la dejas libre xD.
- En el método principal `main()` no debes volver a lanzar las excepciones que puedan salir (`throws`), tienes que capturarlas.

Aquí tienes la solucion:

```
import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

public class VeureInfo {

    public static void veureinfo(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException{

          File origen = new File(filePath);


          if (origen.isFile()){
           System.out.println("Java VeureInfo " +origen.getAbsolutePath());
           System.out.println("INFORMACIÓ: Informació sobre el fitxer:");
           System.out.println("Nom del fitxer : "+origen.getName());
           System.out.println("Ruta : "+origen.getPath());
           System.out.println("Ruta Absoluta : "+origen.getAbsolutePath());
           System.out.println("Es pot escriure : "+origen.canWrite());
           System.out.println("Es pot lleguir : "+origen.canRead());
           System.out.println("Grandaria : "+origen.length()+(" bytes"));

          }else{

             System.out.println("directorio") ;
          }

       }


    public static void main(String args[]) {


        try {
            veureinfo(args[0]);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException error) {
            System.out.println(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: omg!! Mil gracias de verdad.. Me pierdo en mil detalles.. T_T

Comment: denada :) poco a poco